# HTML - TelerikLiveTile center of page

Tags: html, css, asp.net, layout, telerik

i want to center some telerik:RadLiveTile elements on my Page, but i dont know how. I've tried many ways found with google but nothing works for me.
Attached, you can find my imagination of the page.
[PAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAksn.png)

One tile looks like this:

```
    <telerik:RadLiveTile
        ID="thridTile"
        runat="server"
        Width="600"
        Height="300"
        UpdateInterval="5000"
        OnClientDataLoadingError="liveTileOnClientDataLoadingError"
        OnClientTemplateDataBound="liveTileOnClientTemplateDataBound"
        Shape="Wide">
        <WebServiceSettings Path="WebService.asmx" />
        <ClientTemplateAnimationSettings Animation="None" />
        <ClientTemplate>
                        #=data#
        </ClientTemplate>
    </telerik:RadLiveTile>
```

Greetings, Marvin

Comment: Try getting simple divs to align as you want them. Then replace them with RadTiles or just put the tiles inside them.

Comment: i already tried this way, but it's not succeeded. However its not dramatically.

Comment: Tiles have float:left and display:inline-block. I don't know what else to say :)